# Probability that exactly one of the inspected products is faulty

Tags: probability

> There are 100 products in a package and 30 of them are faulty. We
>   inspect 5 product from the package using sampling without replacement.
>   What is the probability that exactly one of the inspected products is
>   faulty?

**Solution attempt:**

Number of ways to pick 1 faulty product from 30 faulty products: $\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {30} \\ 
  1 
\end{array}} \right)$

Number of ways to pick 4 non-faulty products from 70 non-faulty products: $\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {70} \\ 
  4 
\end{array}} \right)$

Number of ways to pick 5 products from 100 products: $\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {100} \\ 
  5 
\end{array}} \right)$

$${\text{P}}({\text{exactly one faulty product)}} = \frac{{\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {30} \\ 
  1 
\end{array}} \right) \cdot \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {70} \\ 
  4 
\end{array}} \right)}}{{\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {100} \\ 
  5 
\end{array}} \right)}} \approx 0.3654$$

Have i solved it correctly?

Comment: In the words of someone's beloved president, Yes you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have solved it correctly. This specific probability distribution is called *hypergeometric*, and if you look at the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution), the formula
$$
P(\text{exactly } k \text{ successes}) = \frac{\binom{K}{k}\binom{N-K}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}
$$
appears, where $K$ is the total number of "successful" products, $N$ is the total number of products, and $n$ is your sample size.

In this case, a product is "successful" if it is faulty, which might seem strange. But it follows the same logic that makes "positive" medical test results a bad thing. It's not about being good or bad, but rather being what you're looking for.